# Is there any way to block GPU throttling programmatically in Acer V3

Tags: c#, java, c++, gpu, throttling

I have problem with GPU throttling in Acer V3-571G. The GPU core slows down from 660 to 270MHz making dedicated card useless. I have not seen any program which allows stoping throttling of GPU. 
Is it possible to get direct access to GPU cores via code(java, c#, c++)?

I add the screen picturing what happens when I run a game Test Drive Unlimited 2... I know I usually work, but hey I paid more to use this GPU sometimes(few times a week).When it does not throttle(first few minutes) everything runs smooth, then FPS go down by 50%.

1. I updated BIOS from 1.08 to 1.13 and it did not help.
2. As far as I know in Acer V3-571G the throttle temperature is set to lower value than it should.

[image]

***BIG EDIT:***

I have tried to read GPU BIOS by GPU-Z and then change throttle temperature by NiBiToR but GPU-Z cannot read the BIOS it says that file `...Local\Temp\\nvflash.rom cannot` be find. This file really exists on my computer but on the location :`...Local\Temp\nvflash.rom` This double slashes in GPU-Z makes this path corrupted in my opinion.

How to fix that and read that rom file correctly.

[image]

Comment: YOu really want to burn up your cpu or damage it? Chance is it throttles for a reason, and you would be a lot better off to find and fix the reason. At least unless something is totally funny. For example up there, it throttles down - with 0 load. GUess what - it makes no difference wheter it throtles or not, as you do not use the card anyway.

Comment: I do use it. It does not slow down on 0 load, but the throttle temperature is set to lower in Acer V3 than in the other notebooks. Please see edit.

Comment: Well, if you use it, why does it show GPU load at 0%?

Comment: @TomTom Because this screenshot was made after I closed the game(only the games uses GeForce GT630m, then it switches to intel HD4000 integrated graphiccs automatically to save energy).

Comment: 65°C is high enough, I wouldn't try pushing it harder.

Comment: @grasGendarme nVidias can take much more as I inquired(more than ATI's), and this is common problem for ACERs->other manufacurers set this throttle temp to higher value. Is this throttling may be caused by PSU(I have 90W PSU)? If not is it possible to change cooling system easily?

Comment: @TomTom Please look at my BIG EDIT section please if you would like to help.